# How to compare two different tensors through matplotlib or any other visualize tools?

Tags: matplotlib, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have two tensors x and y, there both are the same dimension shape = (1, 64, 1, 1)

basically y is output from many functions, and x is the input

I want to compare these two tensor using visualize tool like matplotlib..etc

anyway to do ?

The below are x and y example, I only post 10 of 64 since the restriction

x

```
tensor([[[[-0.8467]],

         [[-0.0949]],

         [[-0.8253]],

         [[-0.1027]],

         [[ 0.0476]],

         [[-0.4173]],

         [[-0.0870]],

         [[ 0.0650]],

         [[ 0.3816]],

         [[ 0.2046]]]], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
```

y

```
tensor([[[[-2.0307]],

         [[-0.1594]],

         [[-1.5174]],

         [[-0.2767]],

         [[ 0.1049]],

         [[-0.9605]],

         [[-0.2127]],

         [[ 0.1342]],

         [[ 0.8275]],

         [[ 2.0508]],
]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `x` and `y` to [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) arrays and then use whatever matplotlib function you want

```py
with torch.no_grad():
  x_np = x.cpu().numpy()[0, :, 0, 0]  # make it 1d
  y_np = y.cpu().numpy()[0, :, 0, 0]
  plt.plot(x_np - y_np)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer， any suggestion for Gaussian ?